# Refactor method header parameter order

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, method-signature

I fighting with a refactoring issue in my Eclipse IDE.

I have this interface method:

```
List<String> evaluateAllPoi(boolean pIsVerified, List<String> pAllNames, List<String> pAllComment);
```

that method has a high test coverage with Junit (at least 90 tests).

I want to move the first `boolean` parameter to the end of the method signature via refactoring so I get:

```
List<String> evaluateAllPoi(List<String> pAllNames, List<String> pAllComment,boolean pIsVerified);
```

I am pretty sure that Eclipse offers a possibility to do that easily, without change each call by hand, but at the moment I do not find/see it.

Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Eclipse does provide a facility for that.

1. Highlight the method name
2. Right-click and go into "Refactor > Change Method Signature..." (alternatively, you can hit <kbd>Alt+Shift+C</kbd>)
3. Change the order of the method parameters by clicking "Up" or "Down". You can also add / remove parameters in this dialog box.
4. Hit "OK".
5. Enjoy.

Picture:

[image]

Comment: 6. Curse at the screwed-up formatting. 7. Fix it. 8. Drink coffee.

Comment: @Tunaki Thx for that excellent answer +1. But I will accept the answer of Andy because you have more upvotes.

Comment: @StefanBeike you're kind, but his answer is a lot better.

Comment: @StefanBeike not to take points away from Andy, but it seems accepting the best answer would be the most useful for future visitors to this question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use "[change method signature](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm)" in the refactoring menu; use the up/down buttons to reorder the parameters.

Comment: ahhrrrr! Its the third point in my context menu. I am tired. time to stop work for today. thx a lot